# How to copy files from HDD to HDD with integrity checking

Tags: linux, backup, data-integrity

I am moving data from an almost dead HDD to an external USB drive using linux , because for some reason Windows cannot see the data.
I want to copy a large amount of data over from the HDD to the USB drive with integrity checking. I thought about copying everything over and then checking with md5summer but this would take a reaally long time because its a lot of data and this is not a very powerful PC.

What tool can use to do this on Linux?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used [`ddrescue`](http://www.gnu.org/software/ddrescue/ddrescue.html) and [`dd_rescue`](http://www.garloff.de/kurt/linux/ddrescue/) for this. (They are two different programs).